# Well tuned orbit camera

Tags: opengl, c++, camera, trigonometry

I have been trying to make an orbit camera using glfw. I got a working solution which is as in the following.

```
float map_range(float s, float a1, float a2, float b1, float b2) {
    return b1 + ((s-a1)*(b2-b1))/(a2-a1);
}

euler_orbit::euler_orbit() {
    _distance = 5;
}
glm::mat4 euler_orbit::getview(){

    return glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, -_distance))
        * glm::eulerAngleXY((float)pitch , (float)yaw );
}
glm::vec3 euler_orbit::getpos(){
    return inverse(getview())[3];
}
void euler_orbit::mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
{
    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_PRESS){
        ldown = true;
        glfwGetCursorPos(window, &lastx, &lasty);
    }
    else if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
        ldown = false;
    }
}
void euler_orbit::cursor_pos_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos){
    if (ldown)
    {
        //this is linear and not working properly 
        //float sensivity = (0.002f * _distance);
        float sensivity = 0.01f;
        pitch -= ( lasty - ypos ) * sensivity;
        yaw -= (lastx - xpos) * sensivity;

        lastx = xpos;
        lasty = ypos;
    }
}
void euler_orbit::mouse_wheel_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset){
    _distance = std::clamp(_distance - yoffset, 1.0, std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
}
```

In above solution there is 1 problem that is constant rotation speed. I am using this camera to view a globe, if you are looking at 1 million kilometers away then its fine becasue 400px movement in X axis(from point A to B, using mouse pointer) results in 1 rev. If you are looking at it from 250 meters away, even a single px of drag can make you view nearby town rather than nearby street. If you check Google Earth you will realize that when you click a place and rotate the world, that place always stays under mouse cursor so i have come up with another plan.

[image]

If i can calculate *a* then i can rotate world as needed. Now the questions are

1. Is this a viable approach?
2. If yes then how can i calculate *a*?
3. Do you have any suggestions?

a = the angle i need to calculate

A = Point of left mouse button down

B = point where user releases the mouse button

Comment: why not just set the camera to move at a constant speed in up/down and left/right then move the camera with the inputs you preffer being them the arrow keys wasd or by moving the mouse....and then just add a button to move the camera further or closer... think of the camera like a player in a third person game, why not?

Comment: I think you'll find that "honest" dragging will feel awful when zoomed out... When the planet is tiny on screen, a few pixels dragging will result in significant motion, and unless you're damping, it'll feel jerky.

I've personally solved this by just having a near- and far- drag speed and lerping between them (or a clamped `rotation_min + rotation_scale * camera_radius`), which is cheap/easy and allows you to over-drag when in close to feel more responsive.

Comment: @Basic that looks like an answer, I'd say.

Comment: @DMGregory I started writing it as an answer but realised I'm not answering the question as asked. If the OP indicates it suits their needs, I'll post it. Otherwise, it'll be here in case someone's looking for an cheap/easy alternative.